# ASP.NET/IIS equivalent of Java/WAS context-root

Tags: java, asp.net, iis

In Java on WebSphere Application Server if I want my servlets, etc., to start with a certain root path, I use the context-root property in the EAR deployment descriptor (application.xml). For example, my servlet is named GetData, but I want the URL to be www.mysite.com/secure/restricted/GetData, so I set the context-root to secure/restricted.

How do I do that in ASP.NET on IIS? Is the some kind of configuration setting for the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be Url Rewritting - http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx

On the other hand, if you have your dynamic asp.net site separated from the rest of your content, you can add the folder secure/ and configure in there through the IIS Manager to point restricted to your asp.net site (regardless of where you have it stored).

That said, I don't know whether the WAS context-root give you something extra, for links to other info outside the asp.net site.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net Core 2.0, there is an applicationUrl property in launchSettings.json:

By default, it will be `"http://localhost:port/GetData" or "http://localhost:port"`

Just change it to your final URL:

```
"http://localhost:port/secure/restricted/GetData"
```